# Select Emails from table depending on a columns status

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called "partners" and I need to select all the email addresses from the table where the column of "salisbury" has a status of yes.

[image]

I then need to concat all the email addresses to put into an email header.

Her's is my code, but it only echos the quEry its self;

```
$partner_emails = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE salisbury ='yes'";

$connect->query($partner_emails);

echo $partner_emails;

@mail($partner_emails, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE salisbury ='yes'
```

A normal select, and just use group_concat to concatenate them with whatever glue you pick.

As far as the PHP goes, it's echoing the query because, you're telling it `echo $partner_emails;`, which is indeed the query. It's been a while since I've used the standard mysqli library, so please forgive any small syntax errors, but try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE salisbury ='yes'";

$connect->query($partner_emails);

if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
    // GET RESULTS
    $row = $result->fetch_row());
    if(!empty($row[0])){
        // SET THE VALUE
        $partner_emails = $row[0];
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: no results<br>";
        $partner_emails = false;
    }

    // CLOSE YOUR RESULTS
    $result->close();
}
else{
    echo "Error in the connection<br>";
    $partner_emails = false;
}

echo "Partner Emails: $partner_emails <br>";

if($partner_emails){
    @mail($partner_emails, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Nice for selecting them, but OP also wants to concat all email adresses to put into an email header.

Comment: @Jaken Herman - Good catch, read it too quickly. Updated to be relevant to the entire question now, thanks!

Comment: I have done that but if I echo the results it just echo's the query and not the results.

Comment: Then you are probably not running the query properly. Check out [example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Post examples of your php code if you'd like help with more than just the MySQL query.

Comment: Updated with my PHP code

Comment: @BradHouston updated my response to include the PHP code. As I said, you may need to play with the syntax a bit because I can't test it at the moment, but it's definitely the direction to go.